# Query missing data from select fields for only 2 records

Tags: ms-access

An often used query joining two tables is missing data of fields from one table for 2 records.  The other records all queried fine. I checked the records and the data type/input mask validity were correct.

```sql
SELECT
    DISPOSITION.PATIENT_ID,
    ADMISSION.LAST_NAME,
    ADMISSION.INBORN,
    DISPOSITION.TRANSFERRED_TO,
    DISPOSITION.[ICN D/C DATE],
    ADMISSION.DOB,
    ADMISSION.BW,
    ADMISSION.GA,
    ADMISSION.RECORD_COMPLETE
FROM
    DISPOSITION
    LEFT JOIN ADMISSION
    ON DISPOSITION.PATIENT_ID = ADMISSION.PATIENT_ID
WHERE (((DISPOSITION.[ICN D/C DATE]) Between #2/26/2016# And #2/29/2016#));
```

After running the query my coworker noticed the incomplete data, entered the missing data into the query fields, which entered a duplicate record into the table for each(key is unique, but not autonumber). I deleted the duplicate records after the problem was brought to my attention, double checked the fields, and yet the query still is missing the fields for just those 2 records?

Any thoughts?  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Compact & repair had no effect unfortunately

Comment: SELECT DISPOSITION.PATIENT_ID, ADMISSION.LAST_NAME, ADMISSION.INBORN, DISPOSITION.TRANSFERRED_TO, DISPOSITION.[ICN D/C DATE], ADMISSION.DOB, ADMISSION.BW, ADMISSION.GA, ADMISSION.RECORD_COMPLETE
FROM DISPOSITION LEFT JOIN ADMISSION ON DISPOSITION.PATIENT_ID = ADMISSION.PATIENT_ID
WHERE (((DISPOSITION.[ICN D/C DATE]) Between #2/26/2016# And #2/29/2016#));  Please forgive the use of patientID as the key for both tables, was done by my predecessor and I am changing the structure.

Comment: It certainly does!  When I get a moment I will attempt to figure out how you surmised that.

Comment: You're describing exactly what is occurring. The only item you haven't touched upon is the fact that there is a matching record in admission.

Comment: That is indeed what I see in the query results, however in the admissions table it's not the case.  The patient id and corresponding fields have a row in admissions.  However, just now I did find next for current document in admissions for the patientID and it returned no results, even though I see the exact ID in the correct column.

Comment: The database is full of protected health information which I can not share.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts HansUp.

Comment: I added your query SQL to the question.  That should make it easier for other readers to analyze.  And the edit may draw attention to this question.  Check whether there is anything else in the comments which should be added into the question itself, and then prune away any comments which are no longer useful.  Or if you've abandoned this question, you may as well just delete it.